# How to render a saved tags in database in react component?

Tags: reactjs, psql

I saved a tag in jsonb column in psql database.

the object was like this

```
{ "render": "<a href="#" target="_blank">click here</a>" }
```

now in reactjs i want to render this in my component i tried by doing this

```
<div>{data.render}</div> // data is the data i get from database
```

the desired output is like this

```
<div><a href="#" target="_blank">click here</a></div>
```

> but what i get is a text inside the div tag

Comment: You could use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). But I'd recommend to rethink your approach and do not store HTML in database. This is a gateway for XSS attack.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko how it's dangerous , can you explain this for me please ? i control this obj, i put it manually in obj in database, is doing so could jeopardize my database security ?

Comment: It should not be a security problem if only admin allowed to change this html. But it immediately become one if at some point of time you decide to allow users to enter tags. Beside security there are other problems, for example portability (what would you do if you need to display this tag in non html UI, say native app?). Consider storing data only `{"url": "#", "text": "click here"}` and let client decide how to render it.